# Finding the correct substitution for integral representaion

Tags: definite-integrals

I have as a part of a problem the following integrals

$\frac{1}{T}\int_{t-T}^t f(\tau) \, \mathrm{d}\tau = \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^T f(t-u) \, \mathrm{d}u$, where $T > 0$ and $u \in [0,T]$

I cannot find the right substition. Can someone provide a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\int_{0}^{T}f(t-u)du \underset{\tau := t-u}{=} -\int_{t}^{t-T}f(\tau)d\tau = \int_{t-T}^{t}f(\tau)d\tau.
$$

Comment: It doesen't matter if I write $0$ or $t$ for the lower bound, respectively, $T$ or $t-T$ for the upper bound?

Comment: @Carlos It matters in the sense that it makes the integral have different signs!

Comment: @ Gudson Chou The rule that after switching the sign also the limits have to be switched I understand. However, the bounds from the left integral are $0$ and $T$. In the middle integral they are $t$ and $t-T$.

Comment: @Carlos Ah, try to prove this $0 \leq u \leq T$ iff $t \leq \tau \leq t-T$.

Comment: Ok I got it: Since for the bounds of the left integral it holds $0 \leq u \leq T$ it holds for the bounds of the right integral, after substitution with $\tau = t-u$:  $0\leq t-\tau\leq T$ $\Rightarrow$ $-t\leq-\tau\leq T-t$ $\Rightarrow$ $t \geq \tau \geq t-T$